# Is it possible to send push notifications using FCM when a change occurs in firebase database without using the console or a 3rd party server?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing an android app which uses firebase database as backend. I need to push notify a particular device when a field in the database gets updated. I've been searching and found examples to do it using php, other servers or the firebase console. Do I really need to get another server?

Comment: Yes, you do need a server for this. Firebase currently doesn't provide a cloud code feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated on 2017-07-02*

Since March 2017 Firebase offers [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), which allows you to run JavaScript functions on Google's servers in response to events in Firebase (such as a database update). The first sample use-case is [Notify users (using Cloud Messaging) when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens), so I recommend reading more about it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send push notification. Because Firebase provides real time syncing of Firebase database. When you add a listener to the database in client it will be called upon every change and can fully control it.
this is an example of registering a change listener:

```
// Write a message to the database
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");

// Read from the database
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

Comment: Keeping an active listener will keep an open connection to the Firebase Database server, which is frowned upon for non-active apps (since it drains the battery). Firebase Cloud Messaging is the generally accepted solution for communicating (from an app server) to an app that may not be actively in use.

Comment: @Wajid Ali But the user wouldn't know the data has been updated unless they open the app. Can I send a push notification from the client side when the listener detects a new data being added?